# Cmake error while configuring openCV with CUDA

Tags: opencv

Cmake is showing this error while configuring openCV with CUDA:

CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:

```
opencv_dep_CUDA_cufft_LIBRARY
    linked by target "opencv_core" in directory C:/opencv/sources/modules/core
    linked by target "opencv_test_core" in directory C:/opencv/sources/modules/core
    linked by target "opencv_perf_core" in directory C:/opencv/sources/modules/core
    linked by target "opencv_flann" in directory C:/opencv/sources/modules/flann
    linked by target "opencv_test_flann" in directory C:/opencv/sources/modules/flann
    linked by target "opencv_imgproc" in directory C:/opencv/sources/modules/imgproc
    linked by target "opencv_test_imgproc" in directory C:/opencv/sources/modules/imgproc
    linked by target "opencv_perf_imgproc" in directory C:/opencv/sources/modules/imgproc
    linked by target "opencv_highgui" in directory C:/opencv/sources/modules/highgui
    linked by target "opencv_test_highgui" in directory C:/opencv/sources/modules/highgui
    linked by target "opencv_perf_highgui" in directory C:/opencv/sources/modules/highgui
    linked by target "opencv_test_features2d" in directory C:/opencv/sources/modules/features2d
    linked by target "opencv_features2d" in directory C:/opencv/sources/modules/features2d
    linked by target "opencv_perf_features2d" in directory C:/opencv/sources/modules/features2d
    linked by target "opencv_calib3d" in directory C:/opencv/sources/modules/calib3d
    linked by target "opencv_test_calib3d" in directory C:/opencv/sources/modules/calib3d
    linked by target "opencv_perf_calib3d" in directory C:/opencv/sources/modules/calib3d
    linked by target "opencv_test_ml" in directory C:/opencv/sources/modules/ml
    linked by target "opencv_ml" in directory C:/opencv/sources/modules/ml
    linked by target "opencv_test_video" in directory C:/opencv/sources/modules/video
    linked by target "opencv_video" in directory C:/opencv/sources/modules/video
    linked by target "opencv_perf_video" in directory C:/opencv/sources/modules/video
    linked by target "opencv_test_legacy" in directory C:/opencv/sources/modules/legacy
    linked by target "opencv_legacy" in directory C:/opencv/sources/modules/legacy
    linked by target "opencv_perf_objdetect" in directory C:/opencv/sources/modules/objdetect
    linked by target "opencv_objdetect" in directory C:/opencv/sources/modules/objdetect
    linked by target "opencv_test_objdetect" in directory C:/opencv/sources/modules/objdetect
    linked by target "opencv_perf_photo" in directory C:/opencv/sources/modules/photo
    linked by target "opencv_photo" in directory C:/opencv/sources/modules/photo
    linked by target "opencv_test_photo" in directory C:/opencv/sources/modules/photo
    linked by target "opencv_perf_gpu" in directory C:/opencv/sources/modules/gpu
```

I have working CUDA without openCV otheriwse.

Comment: So, have you tried setting this variable to the path to cufft library?

Comment: @Drop I asked it becuase I don't know how this is done? Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to choose Visual Studio 11 Win64 instead of Visual Stuidio 11 as generator in CMAKE. this will lead to clean configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Choose the Visual Studio Win 64 version when CMake prompts for a compiler. cufft.lib should be located in your CUDA/vX.x/lib/x64 folder.